# TFS Version Compare Unnecessarily Crossing Out Lines

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

Whenever I am comparing a file and there is a difference in the line, the comparison tool puts a strikeout through the line making it very hard to read that side. Other developers using the same on-prem instance of TFS don't see this line. It is really annoying.

I'm using the web interface of TFS 2018. I've looked on the web for a setting that might be at fault for this, but can't find anything.

[image]